# When I open the terminal on OS X it prints login history for past seven months, would like to fix

Tags: bash, path-variables

As the title reads, upon starting the terminal on OS X 10.10.3 it has started printing the login history for the past six months, and it also states 'command not found' three times and displays my $PATH environment variable. Not sure why it's doing this, I recently edited the $PATH file and this is when it started so I'm assuming it's the cause.

I'd just like to get my terminal to start without this extraneous hullabaloo, as it once did.

Comment: please, provide your content of the file you were editing. There will be probably some typo causing this behaviour.

Comment: What do you mean by "$PATH file"?  Do you mean your `.profile`, `.bash_profile` or similar?